# how to use the Spanish word "pensar" , in propositions

Tags: verbos

I need some examples of the use of  the Spanish verb  "pensar" , in propositions containing also other verbs  ,nouns or pronouns  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Pienso, luego existo.* - I think, therefor I am.
2. *Marta piensa que su hijo es un genio.* - Marta thinks his son is a genius.
3. *Raúl piensa comprarse una casa.* - Raúl is thinking about buying a house.
4. *Déjame pensar el problema.* - Let me think about the problem.
5. *No lo pienses tanto.* - Don't think about it too much.
6. *Sandra piensa en su novio.* - Sandra thinks in her boyfriend.

Samples 1. and 6. are intransitive (*«en su novio»* is not a direct object), while samples 2, 3., 4. and 5. are transitive with object being a subordinate proposition (*«que su hijo es un genio»*), a verb (*«comprarse»*), a noun (*«el problema»*) and a pronoun (*«lo»*).

Answer (score 0):

"Pienso que no deberías ir" (verb)

"Pienso en ti" (pronoun)

"Pienso en María" (noun)

As you can see, 'pensar' is constructed with 'que' or 'en'.

Answer (score 0):

Also as an adverb

"Pienso como un niño" (think as a child)

"Pienso como si estuviera borracho" (think as if i were drunk"

"Pienso al revés" (?)(meaning that you think different or totally oposed to someone)

"Pienso cada vez más" (?) (meaning that you think more over time)